# MaterializeCss Collapsible element got "collapsed" after adding some functions

Tags: javascript, materialize

I use MaterializeCss collapsible element. I initialized it with JavaScript in a templated html file:

```
//activates collapsible bars
var collaps = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
M.Collapsible.init(collaps);
```

Then I added a few functions (different functions at different times) to that file and the collapsible stopped working: when I press it, it doesn't expand.

I don't use any other framework etc.

I have read other topics similar to this where people say it's because of array.push methods and suggest to re-initialize collapsible.

I tried to re-initialize and it didn't change anything.
Either I do it improperly or there's something else to it.

What is the theory of why this happens and how to solve it?

The functions I added now is below (I didn't get to modify them for my data but then this happened). It's about reading values of checkboxes and `<a>` tags (elements inside collapsible element) and calling backend functions.

```js
function getCheckedNames() {
    
     //getting all checkboxes
  const allCheckboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filled-in"));

  //getting all <a> tag elements as a native Array.
  const names = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

  //Reduce from all names to only those that are "checked."
  return allCheckboxes.reduce((arr, cb, i) => {
    // Store the corresponding employee name for any checked checkbox 
    if (cb.value === true)
      arr.push(names[i].value);
   
      return arr;
  }, []);
 }


function requestCals() {

 const chosenNames = function getCheckedNames()
 
 google.script.run
    .withUserObject(chosenNames)
    .withSuccessHandler(requestCalendarEvents)
    .loopToGetCals(JSON.stringify({names: chosenNames}));
}

    
function requestCalendarEvents(calendars, chosenNames) {

 if (typeof calendars === "string")
    calendars = JSON.parse(calendars);
  if (typeof chosenNames === "string")
    chosenNames = JSON.parse(chosenNames);
  if (!chosenNames)
    chosenNames = getCheckedNames();

   const employees = {
    names: chosenNames,
    cals: calendars
  };
  
   //read inputs of start and end dates
  const startdate = document.getElementById("startDate").value
  const enddate = document.getElementById("endDate").value
  

   //getting dates as UTC milliseconds
  const startDate = new Date(startdate).getTime();
  const endDate = new Date(enddate).getTime();
  

  //call backend function to get calendar events
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(getCalendarEvents)
    .getCalendarEvents(JSON.stringify(employees) startDate, endDate);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet? We can't help you if you does not share anything.

Comment: collapsible https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Comment: Well if you just added "a few" functions, why not remove them again and re-add them one by one and see which one breaks your code..

Its quite hard for us to suggest anything without more (if not all) your code..

Comment: Added functions and updates the description. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the functions one by one and only getCheckedNames() doesn't get Collapsible to fail. 2 other interfere with it somehow.

Comment: It works now. But I still don't really get what pieces of code causes such issues.

Comment: Well you might have an error in requestCalc where you wrote :
const chosenNames = function getCheckedNames() where I believe you should omit the "function" keyword..  ..youre calling a function not declaring it.   This might've corrupted your entire execution flow.

Comment: Haha that's true! I accidently put it. It collapsed the html! Thanks!!